# Construct member name to retrieve description from XML comments file | Type.GetGenericArguments() returns incorrect result

Tags: .net, generics, types, reflection, parameters

We have a legacy WinForms app for .NET Framework. A part of this app is a module that reads an assembly's documentation from the accompanying XML comments file. The code has worked without problems for many years, but recently we have found one flaw. Let's consider the following class demonstrating the issue:

```C#
public class Class1<T1, T2>
{
    public struct MyStruct<TS1, TS2>
    {
        public TS1 StructField1;
    }

    public void Method1(T1 arg1)
    { }
    public void Method2(T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
    { }
    public void Method3(MyStruct<string, T1> arg1)
    { }
    public void Method4(MyStruct<T2, int> arg1)
    { }
}
```

`Method3` and `Method4` has the following records in the XML comments file:

```xml
<member name="M:TestSimple.Class1`2.Method3(TestSimple.Class1{`0,`1}.MyStruct{System.String,`0})">
    <summary>
    Method3 summary.
    </summary>
    <param name="arg1">Argument #1.</param>
</member>
<member name="M:TestSimple.Class1`2.Method4(TestSimple.Class1{`0,`1}.MyStruct{`1,System.Int32})">
    <summary>
    Method4 summary.
    </summary>
    <param name="arg1">Argument #1.</param>
</member>
```

To access them, we need to obtain strings

```
M:TestSimple.Class1`2.Method3(TestSimple.Class1{`0,`1}.MyStruct{System.String,`0})
```

and

```
M:TestSimple.Class1`2.Method4(TestSimple.Class1{`0,`1}.MyStruct{`1,System.Int32})
```

for `Method3` and `Method4` respectively. I will not place all code that constructs these strings using reflection because it will take many screens. I just show the problem part in which the parameter description string for `MyStruct` is not constructed properly. It turned out, that the .NET [Type.GetGenericArguments()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getgenericarguments) method does not return a correct list of parameters for `MyStruct` passed as the argument to the following method:

[image]

As you can see, we have 4 parameters for `MyStruct`, though I expect just 2. The documentation for `GetGenericArguments` states that we must use the [Type.IsGenericParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isgenericparameter) property to filter out unneeded parameters in the returned list, but it does not help. As you can see from the screenshot, the parameter `T1` is duplicated in the list of parameters for 'Method3'. The same happens for `Method4`: `GetGenericArguments` returns two entries for `T2`.

Is there a robust way to get the list of parameters for generic structs like `MyStruct` in classes like I showed?

And a general question: maybe, there is a standard method in .NET I can use for a [Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type) instance to retrieve its equivalent member name in the XML comments file? It must be a trivial task, or maybe someone already wrote such a class or method I just couldn't find.

---

If someone wants to look at the current implementation of the `GetGenericClosedConstructedTypeArgumentsString` method from the screenshot above, it is below:

```C#
private static string GetGenericClosedConstructedTypeArgumentsString(Type type)
{
    Type[] myArgumentTypes = type.GetGenericArguments();

    StringBuilder myResult = new StringBuilder();

    myResult.Append(ConstsXmlHelp.cGenericMethodParameterArgumentListStart);

    foreach (Type myArgumentType in myArgumentTypes)
    {
        if (myArgumentType.IsGenericParameter)
        {
            if (myArgumentType.DeclaringType != null && myArgumentType.DeclaringType != type)
            {
                #region Check whether the current argument type is declared in an enclosing type

                bool myIsArgumentTypeDeclaredInEnclosingType = false;
                Type myEnclosingType = type.DeclaringType;
                while (myEnclosingType != null)
                {
                    if (myEnclosingType == myArgumentType.DeclaringType)
                    {
                        myIsArgumentTypeDeclaredInEnclosingType = true;
                        break;
                    }

                    myEnclosingType = myEnclosingType.DeclaringType;
                } 

                #endregion

                if (myIsArgumentTypeDeclaredInEnclosingType)
                    continue;
            }
        }

        if (myResult.Length > ConstsXmlHelp.cGenericMethodParameterArgumentListStart.Length)
            myResult.Append(ConstsXmlHelp.cParameterDelimeter);

        // GetFullName() below returns the generic or string
        // argument equivalent like `0, `1, or System.Int32
        myResult.Append(GetFullName(myArgumentType));
    }

    myResult.Append(ConstsXmlHelp.cGenericMethodParameterArgumentListEnd);

    return myResult.ToString();
}

internal static class ConstsXmlHelp
{
    public const string cParameterDelimeter = ",";
    public const string cGenericMethodParameterArgumentListStart = "{";
    public const string cGenericMethodParameterArgumentListEnd = "}";
}
```

Comment: The method is correct -- `MyStruct` really does have 4 type parameters on the runtime level. You can easily see this looking at the IL. C#'s rules for naming nested types, and the format the XML docs allow/require, are another matter entirely. You would need to check if the type is nested (i.e. has a `DeclaringType`) and leave off the initial parameters from its parent type.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I've added the source code of the `GetGenericClosedConstructedTypeArgumentsString` method to the question. It seems, the method should do what you wrote. Or is something wrong?

Comment: @JeroenMostert and others, Does anybody know how `Type.GetGenericArguments()` works? I may surmise that the first items in the returned array are the generic arguments in the class declaring the method. Knowing this, we could simply skip these first items in the array, and the remaining items would be the `MyStruct` generic arguments we need. Is this true?

Comment: @JeroenMostert, see my suggested answer. It contains the new version of `GetGenericClosedConstructedTypeArgumentsString` that works correctly in all my tests.

Answer (score 0):

I dared to assume that first items in the array returned by `Type.GetGenericArguments()` are the generic types from the type declaring the method, and their number is equal to the number of the declaring method's generic parameters. Taking this, I rewrote the `GetGenericClosedConstructedTypeArgumentsString` method as the following:

```c#
private static string GetGenericClosedConstructedTypeArgumentsString(Type type)
{
    Type[] myArgumentTypes = type.GetGenericArguments();

    if (type.DeclaringType != null)
    {
        myArgumentTypes = myArgumentTypes.Skip(type.DeclaringType.GetGenericArguments().Count()).ToArray();
    }

    StringBuilder myResult = new StringBuilder();

    myResult.Append(ConstsXmlHelp.cGenericMethodParameterArgumentListStart);

    foreach (Type myArgumentType in myArgumentTypes)
    {
        if (myResult.Length > ConstsXmlHelp.cGenericMethodParameterArgumentListStart.Length)
            myResult.Append(ConstsXmlHelp.cParameterDelimeter);

        // GetFullName() below returns the generic or string
        // argument equivalent like `0, `1, or System.Int32
        myResult.Append(GetFullName(myArgumentType));
    }

    myResult.Append(ConstsXmlHelp.cGenericMethodParameterArgumentListEnd);

    return myResult.ToString();
}
```

In all my tests it works correctly. Even for such bizarre method definitions like the following ones:

```c#
public void Method5(MyStruct<T2, MyStruct<decimal, float>> arg1) { }

public void Method6(MyStruct<T2, MyStruct<decimal, T1>> arg1) { }

public void Method7<TM>(MyStruct<T2, MyStruct<decimal, TM>> arg1, TM arg2) { }
```

I just need a confirmation from people knowing the topic of .NET reflection good that my assumption is right.